# Error in Latex-mode

Tags: latex, minor-mode

I keep getting an error in Latex-mode while moving up and down the lines with a cursor: wrong-type-argument stringp nil and a beep on every move. I got the newest version. What can be the problem? (I am using emacsforosx)

This is the debug report

```el
(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  font-info(nil)
  default-font-height()
  default-line-height()
  line-move(1 nil nil 1)
  next-line(1 1)
  funcall-interactively(next-line 1 1)
  call-interactively(next-line nil nil)
  command-execute(next-line)
```

Comment: Do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET` - now when you get the error, you should also get a Backtrace. Edit your question and add the backtrace.

Comment: Is this in GUI emacs or in terminal emacs? If you evaluate `(display-multi-font-p)` what do you get? You should get `t` in GUI emacs, `nil` in terminal emacs. If you get `t`, evaluate `(face-font 'default)`: that's probably `nil`, and that's where the problem lies. To evaluate a form, type it into the `*scratch*` buffer and press `C-j` after it.

Comment: (display-multi-font-p)
t
(face-font 'default)
"-*-Helvetica-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1"